# Can I create a Lion vm from currently running mac

Tags: macos

I have a Mac running Lion. I want to create a vm by copying my current system. In other words, I don't want to create a VM from scratch. I want the VM to match my existing Mac.

I have access to VMware and Parallels but don't see how to create a nre VM by taking a snapshot of my system.

I'm wondering if I can create an image using a Time Machine backup???

Answer (score 0):

If you have a current time machine backup of your host system, you should be able to create a new VM, boot it from your OS X install DVD, connect the Time Machine backup drive to the VM, and restore a backup onto the VM.